# What is the equivalant of a vb.net 'friend' keyword in java?

Tags: c#, java, vb.net, friend, internal

I want to program an internal(in C#) class, I was using the keyword 'Friend' in vb.Net.
Now I want do the same in Java. What is the equivalent?

```
Friend Class NewClass

End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `friend` in Java.  The best you can do is to put the two classes in the same package, and make members of one class package-private (that is, without `public`, `private` or `protected`) to make them accessible to the other.

Answer (score 1):

There is not key word friend or equivalent to friend in Java. When I converted the VB code:

```
Friend Class NewClass

End Class
```

to C# code the conversion I got is:

```
internal class NewClass
{

}
```

So to make it equivalent java code two things you have to do:

1st Keep the class in same package where you want to access it.
2nd declare class without any access modifier:

```
class NewClass
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

C#'s internal is equivalent to Java's default scope (which is its own scope).

Java does not have internal.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Basic.NET, the `Friend` keyword speaks about accessibility.  In C#, the equivalent keyword is `internal`.

In Java, there is no such keyword, but you can get effectively the same visibility with regard to package scope by leaving off any access specifier on the class declaration.

Taken from [a side-by-side comparison](http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/internal.html) between the C# and Java versions of the same class declarations, (I've also added a Visual Basic version for completeness) note the declarations of `class B` as well as `A.Y`, `B.Y`, `C.Y` and `D.Y`:

### The Visual Basic Version:

```
Public Class A
    Public Shared X As Integer
    Friend Shared Y As Integer
    Private Shared Z As Integer
End Class
Friend Class B
    Public Shared X As Integer
    Friend Shared Y As Integer
    Private Shared Z As Integer
    Public Class C
        Public Shared X As Integer
        Friend Shared Y As Integer
        Private Shared Z As Integer
    End Class
    Private Class D
        Public Shared X As Integer
        Friend Shared Y As Integer
        Private Shared Z As Integer
    End Class
End Class
```

### The C# Version:

```
public class A
{
    public static int X;
    internal static int Y;
    private static int Z;
}
internal class B
{
    public static int X;
    internal static int Y;
    private static int Z;
    public class C
    {
        public static int X;
        internal static int Y;
        private static int Z;
    }
    private class D
    {
        public static int X;
        internal static int Y;
        private static int Z;
    }
}
```

### The Java Version:

```
public class A
{
    public static int X;
    static int Y;
    private static int Z;
}
class B
{
    public static int X;
    static int Y;
    private static int Z;
    public class C
    {
        public static int X;
        static int Y;
        private static int Z;
    }
    private class D
    {
        public static int X;
        static int Y;
        private static int Z;
    }
}
```

See also [this comparison of Visual Basic and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9978/Complete-Comparison-for-VB-NET-and-C) for reference.